# Solve PDE : $U^2_x + U^2_y + 1 = \frac{1}{U^2}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Here is the PDE : $U^2_x + U^2_y + 1 = \frac{1}{U^2}$

I tried to solve it using separation of variables method.
Assume $U=XY$; $U_x = \dot X Y$ and $U_y = X \dot Y$

so the PDE become : $(\dot X Y)^2 + (X \dot Y)^2 + 1 = \frac{1}{(XY)^2}$

$(\dot X Y)^2 + (X \dot Y)^2 = \frac{1}{(XY)^2} - 1$

My goal is to make the RHS become $0$ however i am stuck.

Comment: what if you solve the homogenous and then assume the particular is proportional to it?

Comment: do you mean i should try to solve the $(\dot X Y)^2 + (X \dot Y)^2 = 0$ first?

Comment: Separation of variables does not help. If you divide your final step by $X^2Y^2$, you get$$\frac{\dot{X}}{X}+\frac{\dot{Y}}{Y}=\frac{1}{(XY)^4}-\frac{1}{(XY)^2}.$$Taking the partial derivative of each side with respect to $X$, say, will give you a pure function of $X$ on the left, but not on the right, so no solutions of the form $XY$ exist.

Comment: Homogeneous solution: $U\! \left(x,y\right)=f_{1}\! \left(y-\mathrm{I} x\right)+f_{2}\! \left(y+\mathrm{I} x\right)-\frac{x^{2}}{2}$

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? A complete integral or a solution satisfying some boundary condition?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Using a Charpit procedure we have:

$$
f(x,y,z,p,q) = p^2+q^2+1-\frac{1}{z^2}
$$

and from

$$
\frac{dp}{f_x+p f_z}=\frac{dq}{f_y+q f_z}=\frac{dz}{-p f_p-q f_q}=\frac{dx}{-f_p}=\frac{dy}{-f_q}
$$

we have

$$
\frac{z^3dp}{p}=\frac{z^3dq}{q}=-\frac{dz}{p^2+q^2}=-\frac{dx}{p}=-\frac{dy}{q}
$$

From

$$
\frac{z^3dp}{p}=\frac{z^3dq}{q}\Rightarrow p = c_1 q
$$

From

$$
\frac{z^3dp}{p}=-\frac{dz}{p^2+q^2}\Rightarrow \frac{dz}{z^3}=-(c_1^2+1)q dq
$$

etc.